# Does PEAR work with HTTP-Authentication?

Tags: php, pear, http-authentication

I installed my own PEAR server with [pirum](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2011/02/09/building-and-maintaining-a-pear-server-with-pirum/). As I don't want anybody downloading my packages I configured a HTTP-Authentication via a `.htaccess`file. Unfortunatley after that I can't discover any channels, nor can I install any packes. It says:

```
File http://my-pear-channel.com:80/rest/c/categories.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required)
```

I already googled but I couldn't find anything helpful. Is there a way that PEAR can handle HTTP Authentication? Like giving it a username and password in any way?

If it is not possible, how can I secure my PEAR repository so that no one can see it or download any packages from it?

Comment: [starting with the documentation which explicitly tells you how it works seems appropriate](http://pear.php.net/manual/nl/guide.users.commandline.channels.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use password-protected channels; see the [documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/nl/guide.users.commandline.channels.php#guide.users.commandline.channels.passwordprotected).

```
$ pear config-set -c pear.company.com username johndoe
config-set succeeded
$ pear config-set -c pear.company.com password secret
config-set succeeded
```

Comment: Actually I still have problems. If I type `pear list-all -c my-pear-channel.com` I get the following error: `File http://my-pear-channel.com:80/pear/rest/c/categories.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required)`

Comment: are you sure you configured username+password for the correct channel? if yes, fire up wireshark and check if username and password get sent.

Comment: Is it possible that you changed your username or password? You should issue a pear clear-cache command to make sure that the installer doesn't use cached data.